# Python "magic method" for customizing the behaviour of the in operator

Tags: python, methods

I know that there are a number of magic methods in python that affect the way an object behaves in certain situations (like defining `__cmp__(self, other)` to change the way it works when compared with another instance of itself), but I was wondering, is there a way to alter the behavior of how the object is called in an 'in' operator?

```
if thing in custom_object:
    call_the_object_in_a_customized_way()
```

Would there be any way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) is the method you're looking for

From [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` is true if and only if `y.__contains__(x)` is true.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do
>   define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is true if some value `z` with `x == z` is
>   produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the
>   iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines
>   `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is true if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x == y[i]`, and all lower integer indices do
>   not raise `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it
>   is as if in raised that exception).

Comment: Thanks, that's a huge help!

Answer (score 4):

Define the function [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) for this. It's invoked when you use the `in` operator.

Demo:

```
>>> class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in (self.a, self.c)


>>> a = Test(1, 2, 3)
>>> 1 in a
True
>>> 3 in a
True
>>> 2 in a
False
```